# How did a Craigslist seller know my name when using the anonymous email system?

Tags: privacy, email, craigslist

I replied to an ad on craigslist. I used my Gmail account to send it to the anonymized craigslist e-mail.

The receiver must have seen my real email address because he knew my name even though I didn't include it in the message.

I thought when sending an e-mail to an anonymized Craigslist e-mail address, the sender's e-mail gets anonymized too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email is anonymized as a seller responding to a Craigslist email, but the *name* field is not.

> PLEASE NOTE: The “real name” field (e.g. Jane Doe) in your email program is passed through to the recipient. Any contact information in the body of your message will pass through unaltered.
>
> https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/email-relay

and in the FAQ:

> Q: How did the poster find out my real name?
> A: The “real name” field your email program provides is passed through to the recipient.